# Google Place API street type list

Tags: google-places-api, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api, google-places

I am using google place to retrieve address, and somehow we want the street(route in google terminology) to be separated into street name and street type. We also want the street type to match an existing column in database. 
But things get difficult when google place sometimes use `XXXX Street` and some times  `XXXX st`
For instance, this is a typical google address

```
{
    administrative_area_level_1: ['short_name', 'VIC'],
    locality: ['long_name', 'Carlton'],
    postal_code: ['long_name', '3053'],
    route: ['long_name', 'Canada Ln'],
    street_number: ['short_name', '12'],
    subpremise: ['short_name', '13']
}
```

But it always shows Canada Lane in the suggestion box.

And sometimes even worse when the abbreviation does not match my local data model. For instance we use `la` instead of `ln` for short of lane. 
It will be appreciated if anyone could tell me where to find a list of street type (and abbreviation) used by google API. Or Is there a way to disable the abbreviation option?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after "street suffixes". These are complicated.

Not only they change across countries and languages, even within the same country and language they can be used in different ways; abbreviations can have multiple meanings: "St" can be "Street" of "Saint"; abbreviations are used or not depending on subtle rules that also change from place to place.

Same goes for cardinal points (North, South, East, West) that are parts of road / street names: "North St" or "N 11st Street"? It's complicated.

If you already have a good amount of addresses, and you only care about addresses in English, you could take the last word from each street name as the suffix. When matching to your own data, allow for abbreviations when matching, rather than trying to expand them.

For instance, don't try to expand "Canada La" into  "Canada Lane" so that it matches "Lane". Instead, expand "Lane" into ["Lane", "La", "Ln"] and match suffixes to all values.

Then you'd need a strategy for "collisions", abbreviations that can mean 2+ suffixes. These seem to be rare, I can't remember any ("St" isn't, because "Saint" isn't a suffix) and USPS' http://pe.usps.gov/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm doesn't seem to have any.